# How to fetch data from MYSQL with AJAX from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, fetch

i want to call my array data from database using ajax. but i don't know the way. im confused in ajax call to show it into text field. how to get array data from my sql query

this the **index.php** looks like..

```
<body>
<div class="container" >
<h2>View data</h2>
<h4>Word List : </h4>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input id="wordlist" type="text" class="form-control" name="wordlist">
        </div><br>
        <button id="display" title="Generate Word">Generate</button>
        <div class="input-single">
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#display").click(function() {
        $.ajax({    
            type: "POST",
            url: "getword.php",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
              $('#wordlist').html(result[0]);
            }        
        }); 
  });
});

</script>
</body>
```

and then this is the url **getword.php** looks like

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = ""; 
$dbname = "wordlist";

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
if (!$con) {
 die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "select kata from word"; 

 $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
 $result = array(); 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    $result[]= $row[0];
 }
 echo json_encode(array('kata'=>$result));  
 mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: For clarification, is there a reason you need to externally call the PHP file? Can't you just build your HTML inside the PHP file and server it in one go, or is there some limitation you have to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id="wordlist"` is an input, what you passing back from the API is a object

```
{
 kata: [...]
}
```

So `$('#wordlist').html(result[0]);` wont work, your need to use `$('#wordlist').val(result.kata[0]);` (note: [val](https://api.jquery.com/val/) not html) for first item, else it will join the values word1,word2,word3 etc

If your intention is not to place all words in a single input then you should change it so it loops over `result.kata` and creates an input for each word etc

Comment: thank u. i've solved using .val. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
I would like to suggest you to debug your code by yourself using following steps :

1.You can check what response you are getting from server side by printing your ajax response data at console to print this use below code.

 success: function(result){
   console.log(result); 
   // $('#wordlist').html(result[0]);
 }
This will print that you are receiving data from server side.
2.Another point is you are handling the response inside an input field if want to print fetch data inside input field then you have to replace $('#wordlist').html(result[0]); from $('#wordlist').val(result[0]); this line from your JavaScript code because it is an input field.
```

Comment: I've checked it through console log as your suggestion. and then the data appear on console. then how to display into the input field? I try your code but in the input field the data turn into Object Object not displaying the true data 

`from $('#wordlist').val(result[0]);`